# What is the ~ character used for in C#

Tags: c#

I came across this piece of code today:

```
File.SetAttributes(excelFileName, File.GetAttributes(excelFileName) & ~
                   (FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```

Never seen it before. Anyone know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx

The ~ operator performs a bitwise complement operation on its operand, which has the effect of reversing each bit. Bitwise complement operators are predefined for int, uint, long, and ulong.

Answer (score 9):

> "What is the ~ character used for in C#"

For info, ~ is also used (*in a different context*) to denote a destructor / finalizer:

```
class Person {
    public Person() {...} // constructor
    ~Person() {...} // destructor
}
```

Note that you **very rarely** need a destructor; usually only when your type *directly* wraps an unmanaged resource (an OS handle, etc).

Answer (score 1):

One place you see this used usually is in seed initialization:

```
Random randomGen = new Random(~(int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
Random otherGen = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Even if these roughly occur in the same "tick" they would be seeded with two different seeds.